# How to ignore non-JSON lines using Pandas read_json(... , lines=True)

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I have a file generated from a live data stream which mainly contains well formed JSON (one JSON record per line), but will occasionally include a non-JSON line such as 'Time out' or 'Connection error'.

A simple `test.json` file looks like this:

```
{"time": "00:00:00", "value": 0}
Time out
{"time": "00:00:01", "value": 1}
```

I'm trying to read this file into a Pandas dataframe, ignoring the non-JSON lines, using:

```
df = pd.read_json('test.json', lines=True, encoding_errors='ignore')
```

... but a ValueError exception is raised due to the non-JSON line.

Is there a way to do this just using a combination of options to read_json()? I've tried combinations of encoding='utf-8', orient='records' etc, but my non-JSON line is not ignored, which I would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this just using `read_json`. But it's easy enough to pre-process it, like this for example:

```
infilename = 'test.json'
outfilename = 'test-cleaned.json'

# df = pd.read_json(infilename, lines=True)  # Fails due to malformed data

with open(infilename) as file, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in file:
        if not line.startswith('{'):  # Malformed line
            continue
        outfile.write(line)

df = pd.read_json(outfilename, lines=True)
df
```

Result:

```
       time  value
0  00:00:00      0
1  00:00:01      1
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that suggestion. I’m doing that sort of thing already, which works. I just spotted the “encoding_errors” option and was hoping “ignore” would do the trick.  I’m thinking of wrapping read_json() in a decorator to do the same job in a cleaner way. Thanks anyway.